# Ошибка записи/чтения картинки андроид

Tags: java, android

Иногда, где-то раз на 100 скачиваний, появляется ошибка ENOENT или EROFS в приложении андроид 4.0.3 при скачивании/выводе картинки в imageview. Решить ошибку помогает перезагрузка девайса. В последнее время количество ENOENT/EROFS резко возросло, хотя в коде ничего не изменял, что касается работы с файлами. Дайте ответ, пожалуйста, на несколько вопросов:

1. Почему это происходит?
2. Проблема скрывается в программном коде или в самом девайсе (для тестирования использую HTC Sensation XE)?
   Ниже привожу код, который используется для скачивания/чтения.

Скачивание:

```
File m_folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/NameDirectory");
        if (!m_folder.exists()) {
            m_folder.mkdirs();
        }
File file = new File(m_folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename.concat(".jpg"));
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
            // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Чтение:

```
final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/DistanFile/"  + m_CURRENT_TYPE + name + m_ID_TEST + "_" + Integer.toString(i)+".jpg";
        final ImageView m_imgv = new ImageView(m_context);
        m_imgv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        view.addView(m_imgv, m_LP_FOR_VIEW_ELEMENTS);
        tasks.add(new Callable<Object>() {
                public Object call() throws Exception {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                    m_ImageView_AL.add(m_imgv);
                    m_Bitmap_AL.add(bmp);
                    return null;
                }
        });
```

В манифесте стоит разрешение:

```
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Comment: Ошибка связана с тем, что файл, который вы пытаетесь отобразить не существует или путь задан до него неверно. Покажите где и как вы вызываете данные функции

Comment: Как тогда объяснить, что все работает корректно большую часть времени, а если появляется ошибка ENOENT или EROFS, то исправляется перезагрузкой девайса? Я знаю, что означают эти ошибки, но я не знаю, что их вызывает, т.к. ничего не изменяется, все время загружается одинаковый контент.

Comment: так а почему тогда не использовать picasso или imageloader?

Comment: Я использую для загрузки imageloader, но сохраняю на диск методом, что указан выше. На сколько я знаю, imageloader не обладает функционалом для сохранения картинки. У меня ошибка именно в сохранении на диск и чтению с него

Comment: Как это не обладает? Все прекрасно обладает)

Comment: Помимо этого, если вы скачиваете картинки, имитируя тем кэширование, то в imageloader-e это уже тоже все реализовано

Comment: Можете скинуть ссылку на пример или документацию, где описано сохранение с помощью imageloader?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016619/how-can-i-just-download-image-with-universal-image-loader Вот тут пример, уберите лишнее из него, и проинициализируйте его в вашем Application-классе